# Why are my items not aligning horizontally in Flexbox navbar?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have been playing around with the navbar from the Youtube video "Animated Responsive Navbar with CSS" from the channel Fireship. I am trying to get the items in my navbar to align to center horizontally. The HTML has the following structure:

```
<nav class="navbar">
  <ul class="navbar-nav">
    <li class="logo">
      <a href="#" class="nav-link">
        <span class="link-text logo-text">Home</span>
```

And my CSS is:

```
.navbar {
    position: fixed;
    background-color: var(--bg-primary);
    transition: width 600ms ease;
    overflow: auto;
  }
  
  .navbar-nav {
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    height: 100%;
  }
  
  .nav-item {
    width: 100%;
  }
  
  .nav-link {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    height: 5rem;
    color: var(--text-primary);
    text-decoration: none;
    filter: grayscale(100%) opacity(0.7);
    transition: var(--transition-speed);
  }
```

As I understand it setting the following should center the items horizontally:

1. Set .navbar-nav to display:flex
2. Set .navbar-nav to flex-direction:column
3. Set .navbar-nav to align-items center;

However, what I end up with is the following:

[image: Left aligned]

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you using Bootstrap?

Comment: @BOZ no I am not. How come?

Comment: It looks like the parent element `.navbar-nav {` is set to column, but the inner element is still in row status. For this, the `.nav-link {` class should be `justify-content: center;` Would you try to add it? If you want, I can explain with an example.

Comment: It would be helpful to provide more of your HTML next time.

Comment: @MongoosePainter Please provide your complete html.

Comment: How are you inserting the logo image? Can you provide you exact and complete html?

Comment: @BOZ that fixed it. Thank you so much for the help.

Answer (score 0):

As said in [this link](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_flex-direction.asp) (w3 schools), try `flex-direction: row`. this is because `flex-direction: column` aligns vertically instead of horizontally

Answer (score 0):

Change `flex-direction: column;` to `flex-direction: row;`

`row` will align items horizontally in a flex-box whereas `column` aligns items vertically as your original result.

```css
html { /* added these rules to better match OG styles in provided picture */
  background-color: #223; color: #dde; font-family: Arial; padding-left: 2rem;
}
.navbar { position: fixed; transition: width 600ms ease; overflow: auto; }
.navbar-nav {
  list-style: none; padding: 0;
  margin: 0; display: flex;
  flex-direction: row; /* changed "column" to "row" */
  align-items: center; height: 100%;
}
.nav-item { width: 100%; }
.nav-link {
  display: flex; justify-content: center; align-items: center; height: 5rem;
  padding: 1rem; /* added padding so you can see nav items better */
  color: var(--text-primary); text-decoration: none;
  filter: grayscale(100%) opacity(0.7);
}
.logo { position: relative; } /* This and below to add logo next to nav items */
.logo::before { 
  display: block; transform: scale( 1.25 ); position: absolute; 
  top: 3rem; width: 1rem; height: 1rem; 
  background-image: url( "https://i.stack.imgur.com/ejyfV.png" );
  background-size: 6rem; background-position: -0.06rem -1rem;
  content: "";
}
.logo:nth-of-type( 1 )::before { background-image: none; }
.logo:nth-of-type( 3 )::before { background-position: -0.06rem -2.85rem; }
.logo:nth-of-type( 4 )::before { background-position: -0.06rem -4.7rem; }
.logo:nth-of-type( 5 )::before { background-position: -0.06rem -6.55rem; }
```

```html
<nav class="navbar">
  <ul class="navbar-nav">
    <li class="logo">
      <a href="#" class="nav-link">
        <span class="link-text logo-text">Home</span>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li class="logo">
      <a href="#" class="nav-link">
        <span class="link-text logo-text">About</span>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li class="logo">
      <a href="#" class="nav-link">
        <span class="link-text logo-text">Work</span>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li class="logo">
      <a href="#" class="nav-link">
        <span class="link-text logo-text">Pricing</span>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li class="logo">
      <a href="#" class="nav-link">
        <span class="link-text logo-text">Contact</span>
      </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```